# ViewPager list refresh is not working properly

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I have custom `ViewPager` and `PagerAdapter` which is loading items inside `instantiateItem`. It is working fine if I initialize it for the first time with set list of items.

But as I call refresh on the list and I want to populate Adapter with new (totally different) list, after calling `viewPager.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()`, PagerAdapter stops working properly and those items are blank pages without content and I can swipe through them in UI.

`PageScreen` is not `Fragment`. It is just `ViewGroup` container which is inflating layout and setting values out of specific item. It is similar to `ViewHolder` + `Binder` in `RecyclerView`.

Also `instatiateItem()` is called only once as i add new list and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. At start it is called 3 items, which is amount of `PageScreen` items in first list.

```
//init
val pages = mutableListOf<PageScreen>()
pages.add(PageScreen(activity, app, itemJs1, onClick = {onItemClicked(itemJs1.id)}))
pages.add(PageScreen(activity, app, itemJs2, onClick = {onItemClicked(itemJs2.id)}))
pages.add(PageScreen(activity, app, itemJs3, onClick = {onItemClicked(itemJs3.id)}))

swipePager.adapter = CustomPagerAdapter(pages).also { it.notifyDataSetChanged() }

...

//on refresh after API call
pages.clear()

contentList.forEach{item-> pages.add(PageScreen(activity, app, item, onClick = {onItemClicked(item.id)}))}

(swipePager.adapter as? CustomPagerAdapter)?.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Also tried this (same result):

```
//on refresh after API call

val newPages = mutableListOf<PageScreen>()

contentList.forEach{item-> newPages.add(PageScreen(activity, app, item, onClick = {onItemClicked(item.id)}))}

swipePager.adapter = CustomPagerAdapter(newPages).also { it.notifyDataSetChanged() }
```

Adapter:

```
class CustomPagerAdapter(private var pageList: MutableList<PageScreen>) : PagerAdapter() {
    override fun isViewFromObject(view: View, `object`: Any): Boolean {
        return view == `object`
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return pageList.size
    }

    override fun destroyItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int, `object`: Any) {
        container.removeView(`object` as View)
    }

    override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): View {
        val layout = pageList[position].getScreen(container)
        container.addView(layout)
        return layout
    }
}
```

Also I tried to properly refresh items (I expect that this is done internally by PagerAdapter and ViewPager when I call `notifyDataSetChanged()`) by removing them from ViewPager contentView and calling `instantiateItem()` for each item. But same result as above. Now every single page was blank. Function below is added to `CustomPagerAdapter`.

```
fun refreshItems(vp: ViewPager, data: MutableList<PageScreen>){
        pageList.apply {
            forEachIndexed{pos, item->
                item.screenView?.let { sv->
                    destroyItem(vp, pos, sv)
                }
            }
            clear()
            addAll(data)
            forEachIndexed { pos, _ -> instantiateItem(vp, pos) }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

UPDATE:
I managed to "fix" this by setting ViewPager height to fixed value instead `WRAP_CONTENT` but its not a solution. I want ViewPager with dynamic height, because some of its children can have different height + setting something to static is not good approach in Android. Some phones with square displays could have cropped page then.

What happened is as I replaced all items, those "blank" pages were items with 0px height and 0px width for some unknown reason.

If I replaced ViewPager height to dp value, it "worked". But as I replaced those Views, first item was always blank. but as I scrolled to third one and back to first, item was there for some reason.

Also I don't get that height problem. I have function inside ViewPager which is setting its height based on tallest child in list. It works if list is static, but it is not working now as I refresh that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recreating whole `ViewPagerAdapter` is a solution for this problem.

I called API inside `onPageSelected()` and remembered position returned to listener function.

Then I recreated whole adapter like this:

```
swipePager.apply {
   adapter = null
   adapter = CustomPagerAdapter(newPages)
   adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
   invalidate()
}
```

and after refresh I scrolled to remembered position like this:

```
setCurrentItem(position, true)
```

This solution will not left blank pages, but I had to set static height for my `ViewPager`, which can be a problem on `mdpi` screens which sometimes cannot redraw particular `dp` value from `XML` layout correctly. Phone with this problem is for example `Sony Xperia E5` which has `xhdpi` screen and part of my `ViewPager` is cropped from the bottom.

This have to be tuned manually with separate `dimens.xml` for both `mdpi` and `xhdpi`.